# Reduce single array containing objects that may or may not have same value into an array of single unique objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping, javascript-objects

Not quite sure how to ask this succinctly. Lets say I have an array of objects such that:

```
`{ title: 'The first title',
published_on: '2018-08-10 21:47:28',
body_content: '',
image_content: 'the first image'},
{ title: 'The first title',
published_on: '2018-08-10 21:47:28',
body_content: 'some content',
image_content: '' },
{ title: 'The second title',
published_on: '2018-08-06 17:08:28',
body_content: '',
image_content: 'an image url' },
{ title: 'The second title',
published_on: '2018-08-06 17:08:28',
body_content: 'a bunch of stuff',
image_content: '' } ]`
```

and what i'm after is the merged objects with the same value with any other keys:

```
`theArrayIWant = [
{ title: 'The first title',
published_on: '2018-08-10 21:47:28',
body_content: 'some content',
image_content: 'the first image' },
{ title: 'The second title',
published_on: '2018-08-06 17:08:28',
body_content: 'a bunch of stuff',
image_content: 'an image url' }
]`
```

I've been trying to find a simple solution for this. I know there must be. I am using spaghettified for loops and many placeholder vars and it just feels wrong

edit: 
The `...etc` i meant to be more of the same type objects. In my example the title property is the only one where there might be an object with the same key. I want them to become a single object if there is a matching one including the properties the matching object might have.

edit 2: I've included the exact objects I'm working with

Comment: please add what *etc* in `theArrayIWant` is. do you have other items in `originalArray` with diffrent `title` property?

Comment: What should be done when there's more than one element with given key - like 'title' in your example, but with different values?

Comment: please post what you have tired so that others need not think in that line.Also increase the data in `originalArray`, it will be helpful instead of making assumptions.

Comment: no prob! Give me a second.

Answer (score 3):

You could collect all properties in a single object who share the same `title` property.

This is done by using an object and `title` as key.

```js
var original = [{ title: "example name", image: "abcd" }, { title: "example name", content: "efgh" }, { title: "another name", image: "some image" }, { title: "another name", content: "some stuff" }],
    result = Object.values(original.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.assign(r[o.title] = r[o.title] || {}, o);
        return r;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Edit for the changed requirement with a check for empty elements.

```js
var original = [{ title: 'The first title', published_on: '2018-08-10 21:47:28', body_content: '', image_content: 'the first image' }, { title: 'The first title', published_on: '2018-08-10 21:47:28', body_content: 'some content', image_content: '' }, { title: 'The second title', published_on: '2018-08-06 17:08:28', body_content: '', image_content: 'an image url' }, { title: 'The second title', published_on: '2018-08-06 17:08:28', body_content: 'a bunch of stuff', image_content: '' }],
    result = Object.values(original.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r[o.title]) {
            r[o.title] = o;
            return r;
        }
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => v === '' || (r[o.title][k] = v));
        return r;
    }, {}));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: With my updated example it drops the image_content but does merge. In my original example i messed up by not including the empty properties.